# Ruby On Rails and Heroku issue when writing in yaml files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

i'm working on rails and deploying my app on heroku.

I have build a translation system and in this system i need to write in yaml files

here is how i proceed :

```
File.open(ENV['PATH_TO_FILE'], 'w') do |f|
    f.write hash.to_yaml
  end
```

In localhost, it works perfectly, in the rails console, when i do

```
YAML::load_file(ENV['PATH_TO_FILE'])
```

i can see the new keys that have been added.

However, after deploying on Heroku, and running the same code in the rails console of heroku, no keys are added.

Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Two items: 1.What file *are* you trying to write to, and do you have write permission for that location on Heroku?  Are there any diagnostics that you can apply to check *that*?  Maybe just open a shell in Heroku and see if you can `touch` the file?  2. Is the code that's supposed to be creating the file running in the same dyno as the console?  Because this link implies that there's a problem if its not: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem

Comment: First of all thank you for you answer! I'm trying to write in config/locales/en.yml, how can i check if i have these permissions on heroku? I can load the file in the console so it seems that i have them! I think that the file is writen temporarly and not saved, but i have no ideas how to solve that :(

Answer (score 1):

Heroku is a [read-only file system](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/read-only-filesystem), so writing to the yaml file won't be possible.

I would explore using a key/value store like [redis](http://redis.io) or similar in place of the yaml file.

Comment: The old Bamboo stack is read-only.  The more modern Cedar stack uses an "ephemeral filesystem."

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Bamboo stack, [Heroku's filesystem is read only](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/read-only-filesystem).

If you're on Cedar, each dyno has its own ephemeral filesystem. Check out [this section of the Heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem)

It's also possible the environment variable PATH_TO_FILE is not set correctly on heroku.
I recommend using the Figaro gem to manage your environment variables
https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro